# How does one include Mariadb in C++ code?

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, which comes with Mariadb installed by default. So I have *mariadb-server-10.3*, *mariadb-server-core-10.3*, *mariadb-client-10.3*.
I have also installed *libmariadb3*, *libmariadb-dev* and *libmariadb-dev-compat*, all from apt, as the site of mariadb suggests for setting up to be able to use the Connector for C/C++ properly (which is included with the server 10.3).

[image]

So given all that, I expected that once coding in some example.cpp file, I would be able include a  or (<mysql.h>) header. However, the compiler never finds the file.

**EDITED**
Code tried:
[simple .cpp code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLoA0.png)

Compiling tried:
[gpp error found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxfsQ.png)

So am I mistyping the header file title, or am I missing something at link stage, or is it even another issue?

Comment: Show your code and the error messages in the question please.

Comment: It's another issue: you forgot the crucial step of checking mariadb's documentation for instructions on how to build C software using their header files and libraries, which should answer this question.

Comment: So I have added the simple code I used to verify some basic code, which did not get through the compilation with gpp. Truth I have not read how to link to mariadb in any mariadb doc, but it is because I have not found it in their website.

Comment: You need to link with either `-lmariadbclient` or `-lmariadb`.

Comment: @PaulT. still don't think there is any reference about linkint to the library there. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Botje Thank you. You were right and I will be able to use it now. I just wish this info was a bit more obvious on their website as some kind of example to verify installation and such.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Botje who commented on the issue, I was successful when compiling the code with -lmariadb annexed to the command, so:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -lmariadb
```

Thank you all who devoted a bit of your time here.